# during npm install getting Failed to parse package.json data

Tags: json, node.js, angular, npm

during npm install on windows 10  i am getting this error 
I am using node v6.10.3 and npm v3.10.10

please help to correct this.

error I am getting

```
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file C:\angular2-helloworld\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '\r' at 5:71
npm ERR!     "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run 
lite\"\
npm ERR!                                                                      
^
npm ERR! File: C:\angular2-helloworld\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. 
JSON.parsenpm ERR! node v6.10.3
```

package.json file contents:

```
{  
   "name":"angular2-helloworld",
   "version":"1.0.0",
   "scripts":{  
      "start":"tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
      "tsc":"tsc",
      "tsc:w":"tsc -w",
      "lite":"lite-server",
      "typings":"typings",
      "postinstall":"typings install"
   },
   "license":"ISC",
   "dependencies":{  
      "angular2":"2.0.0-beta.14",
      "systemjs":"0.19.25",
      "es6-shim":"^0.35.0",
      "reflect-metadata":"0.1.2",
      "rxjs":"5.0.0-beta.2",
      "zone.js":"0.6.6"
   },
   "devDependencies":{  
      "concurrently":"^2.0.0",
      "lite-server":"^2.2.0",
      "typescript":"^1.8.9",
      "typings":"^0.7.12"
   }
}
```

Comment: What tsc task do? Also why in your start script you start tsc without `npm run` but you start `tsc:w` as `npm run tsc:w`?

Comment: `\r` means a carriage return. NPM is complaining about a carriage return at the very end of line 5. What text editor are you using to make changes to `package.json`?

Comment: I am using notepad ++ to make changes in it

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an invisible character `\r` at line:

```
"start":"tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
```

That character breaks the json parsing of the `package.json` file.
Try to rewrite that part of the text by hand, or use a regex search to delete it in your text editor.